# Function overloading with Object type and string type parameters

Tags: casting, overloading

I have done the following bit of code

```
public Class OverLoading {

public void Get(int val, string str)
{
    Console.Write("Method with int and string parameter");
}
public void Get(int str, object obj)
{
    Console.Write("Method with int and Object parameter");
}
```

}

When I call it from Main() using the below mentioned code, the line "obj.Get(2, null)" always calls the first Get method of Overloading class i.e. Get(int val, string str)

```
static void Main()
    {
        OverLoading obj = new OverLoading();
        obj.Get(2, null);
    }
```

Can you please suggest, why the null getting casted to string and not to object.

Answer (score 0):

Because int the Java programming language Strings are objects. Hence they can be set to null.
Primitive Data types cannot be set to null. 
byte
short
int
long
float
double
boolean
char

To set null values for them, you will have to use the corresponding wrapper

Refer:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 0):

Because *String* is the child of *Object*.
While resolving overloaded methods,compiler will always look child type argument method first.